# Change image according to theme in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

What would be the best way to change the source of an image according to a theme selected? Ideally you will just have a CSS for each theme and set the image as a backround for example (that is what I currently do).

However what I need to do now is use an actual image that is functional and is part of the presentation, it is not just an image that is part of the design. This image will look slightly different depending on the theme.

I am saving the theme that each user has selected in the database. I want to be able to change the source of the image when a user requests a page according to the theme in the database. I am using dependency injection (StructureMap), MVC 4 and EF 5. I want to somehow assign value to ViewBag.MyImagePath in my _Layout page and then all pages to just have src="@ViewBag.MyImagePath".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a theme aware image helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ThemeAwareImage(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string image, 
        string alt = ""
    )
    {
        var context = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var theme = context.Session["theme"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theme))
        {
            // the theme was not found in the session 
            // => go and fetch it from your dabatase
            string currentUser = context.User.Identity.Name;
            theme = GetThemeFromSomeDataStore(currentUser);

            // cache the theme in the session for subsequent calls
            context.Session["theme"] = theme;
        }

        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        img.Attributes["alt"] = alt;
        img.Attributes["src"] = urlHelper.Content(
            string.Format("~/images/{0}/{1}", theme, image)
        );
        return new HtmlString(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

which could be used in your views to render those images:

```
@Html.ThemeAwareImage("foo.jpg", "This is the foo image")
```

As a better alternative to using the `Session` to store the current user theme you could cache it in a cookie or even better make it part of your routes in which case your site will be much more SEO friendly.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the SEO tip too. However I do not understand how this is more SEO friendly - can you elaborate on this one?